# SQL Server Reporting Services: 3rd-Party Chart Controls?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

We have an opportunity to purchase 3rd-party chart controls for SQL Server Reporting Services.

We are currently using SQL Server 2005 database engine and reporting services, but are contemplating going to 2008 within the next 6 months to a year.

What 3rd-party charting controls do you use?

What do you see as the good and bad points for (a) that vendor and (b) individual controls within the set you purchased?

Many thanks!
SteveR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dundas charts for reporting services](http://dundas.com/Products/Chart/RS/Features/NewFeatures.aspx) is something you should be looking at.

The good -

- Amazing levels of flexibility
- Good quality charts
- Large number of chart types (scorecards, contours, etc)
- SQL Server Reporting services charts are actually based on Dundas technology

The bad

- Not exactly cheap
- API is not intuitive in places, but you soon get a feel for it

You can also take a look at [Nevron Charts for Reporting Services](https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-overview.aspx)

Full disclosure: I'm in no way shape or form affiliated with Dundas

Answer (score 1):

Dundas charts are no longer in development. If you are looking to extend the standard charting in reporting services 2005, 2008, 2012, or SQL Server 2014, you should take a look at: [Nevron Chart for SSRS](https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-overview.aspx)

Full disclosure: I'm in no way affiliated with Nevron

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at Micro charts